# When does a tag badge become trackable?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges

With a [recent answer that was well received](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295367/unsold-atari-videogames-dumped-in-a-desert/295370#295370) that I posted, I (at time of posting) have gained a score of 63 for the [atari-2600](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-2600), [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history), and [e.t.-extra-terrestrial](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t.-extra-terrestrial) tags.  Currently, that makes 1 answer, with a score of 63 for each of these tags, which you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: tag scores]

Now out of the list of my trackable badges, none of these three are available to choose from.  When does a tag become trackable?  I've noticed that none of these tags have 20 or more questions.  Is that why (since you need to have at 20 answers posted for each tag)?

Comment: I've experienced the same problem with "pokemon-sm" a couple of weeks ago, now there are 113 questions tagged and it can be tracked.

Comment: @pinckerman Unfortunately, I don't think one of the worse games in history, a console from 1977, or gaming history will ever have more than 100 questions.

Comment: Well, gaming history maybe...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tag badges actually become trackable once there are at least ***100*** questions tagged with a given tag, rather than 20, as you can see in the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work).

Right now, [atari-2600](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-2600) has 9 questions tagged with it, [e.t.-extra-terrestrial](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e.t.-extra-terrestrial) has 3, and [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) has 17, so it'll be a while before tag badges for those tags become available.